# Some browsers can't load embedded flash videos

Tags: html

I have some videos at mypace.com. and I added them to an html page. One of my friend warned me (and he had been warned by others) that he couldn't see the videos.

This problem occures with these systems as far as I know:

- Windows 7 + Google Chrome 16.0.899.0 (with a warning about update server)
- Pardus (Linux) + Firefox 7.0.1

I guess a trojan may cause this but many people have this problem. These people are using their browser without any other problem.

I want to share some of my code:

```
                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>

                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>

                            <param name="movie" value="http://mediaservices.myspace.com/services/media/embed.aspx/m=0,mr=110475301,t=1,mt=video"/>

                            <param name="QUALITY" value="high" />

                    </object>

                    <br />

                    <br />

                    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="425px" height="360px">

                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>

                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>

                            <param name="movie" value="http://mediaservices.myspace.com/services/media/embed.aspx/m=0,mr=110475417,t=1,mt=video"/>

                            <param name="QUALITY" value="high" />

                    </object>

                    <br />

                    <br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash material, as this is the accepted 'cross-compliant" means of doing so.  Even the [HTML5 Boilerplat](http://html5boilerplate.com/)e examples and [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) HTML5 demos come with SWFObject pre-installed.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for years. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  It saved me a lot of hassle when I found out about it.  The HTML5 boilerplate itself is also a good place to start from, but I have no idea what Moderizer or the JavaScript whatever thing does; so I take them out of it when I start.  I love what it teaches about apple-touch-icons and other little-known tweaks for sites.